# How to do something after i initialize lateinit?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a AutoCompleteTextView with custom adapter, the custom adapter get it's list from a LiveData so i initialize it inside the observe method.

The issue is that i even need to set it's value by using `adapter.getItem()` but when i try to cast it i get the error that my adapter is not initialized:

> lateinit property adapterFornitori has not been initialized

So what would be the best way to call my function which set the AutoCompleteValue only after my adapter has been initialized?

Here is my code:

```
// function which initialize my adapter
private lateinit var adapterFornitori: AutoCompleteAdapter
private fun initFornitori(testata: Testata) {
    corpoViewModel.selectFornitori().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        adapterFornitori =
            AutoCompleteAdapter(requireContext(), it.toMutableList(), R.layout.list_item)
        autocompleteFornitore.setAdapter(adapterFornitori)
    }).also {
        setFornitore(testata.cod_fornitore)
    }
}

private fun setFornitore(codFornitore: String?) {
    if (codFornitore != null) {
            autocompleteFornitore.tag = "SET"
            autocompleteFornitore.setText(
                adapterFornitori.getItemByCode(codFornitore).desc,
                false
            ) // getting value from my adapter
    }
}
```

And i'm calling that functions from my onViewCreated of the Fragment like:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
    ... // code code code
    .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
          when (it.tipo) {
                "Carico" ->
                    initFornitori(testata)
                ...
            }
    }
 }
```

So which would be the right way to initialize the Adapter and only then call the setFornitore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
also {
        setFornitore(testata.cod_fornitore)
    }
```

you are calling at the time you set the observer, which is before the observer is ever called, so the property hasn't been set yet. You should move that code inside the observer:

```
private fun initFornitori(testata: Testata) {
    corpoViewModel.selectFornitori().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        adapterFornitori =
            AutoCompleteAdapter(requireContext(), it.toMutableList(), R.layout.list_item)
        autocompleteFornitore.setAdapter(adapterFornitori)
        setFornitore(testata.cod_fornitore)
    }
}
```

---

Unrelated to your problem:

In my opinion, this is improper use of `lateinit`. It's intended for properties that can't be initialized in the constructor, but can be initialized in `onCreate()` (or equivalent first entry point of classes where the constructor is not a usable entry point for your own code). So you should almost always initialize all `lateinit` properties directly in `onCreate()`.

Since in this case, you cannot initialize it until later, it is more appropriate to make it a nullable property and initialize it with `null`. Then, wherever you use it, you'll have to appropriately handle the possibility that it has not been set with a nonnull value yet.

Comment: As you suggested i changed my adapter from lateinit to `private var adapterFornitori: AutoCompleteAdapter? = null` and just moved the setFornitore() inside the observable by solving the issue.

Answer (score -1):

you can set

```
 if (::adapterFornitori.isInitialized){
       autocompleteFornitore.tag = "SET"
                autocompleteFornitore.setText(
                    adapterFornitori.getItemByCode(codFornitore).desc,false)
    }
```

Comment: this won't work as the `if` returns false as adapterFornitori is not yet initialized, so the value is not set anyway